# Why is the row count increasing but the max id does not change?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

This is ... interesting. I'm trying to delete a bunch of records (~2 million) in a table. After waiting for about 4 hours for a simple delete to finish, I started investigating.

```
delete from mytable where date > getutcdate()
```

If I do a few count queries, the total row count increases but the max id (identity) does not change.

```
select count(1) from mytable with(nolock)
select max(Id) from mytable with(nolock)
```

I made sure I had the only connections open by killing every session that wasn't from my IP address.

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_connections
kill 123
kill 124
kill 125
-- etc
```

Yet still, the total row count increases and the max Id stays the same. What on earth could cause this??

**Update**

It look like my original query is still running. I swear I already killed it, but if I try to kill it now, it says "Command(s) completed successfully", but it still shows as running if I run this query again:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections c
     ON  s.session_id = c.session_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_task_space_usage tsu
     ON  tsu.session_id = s.session_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_os_tasks t
     ON  t.session_id = tsu.session_id
          AND t.request_id = tsu.request_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r
     ON  r.session_id = tsu.session_id
         AND r.request_id = tsu.request_id
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) TSQL
```

**Update 2**

The row count finally stopped going up, and the locks are released, so it does appear that it was rolling back for a couple hours. With some help from my boss, who just happened to be online tonight (it's 2 AM EST), we rebuilt a few indexes and tried a different approach.

```
DELETE_MORE:
    DELETE TOP(5000) from mytable where date > getutcdate()
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 GOTO DELETE_MORE
```

Yes, that's a GOTO. Yes, that's the only reason I've ever found in my professional career to use one. Now that that's out of the way ... this will delete rows in groups of 5000, minimizing locks and rollbacks if it fails. This seems to be working well as it is running as I type this.

Comment: Was the delete still executing or rolling back when you began investigating?

Comment: Well, I cancelled the query in management studio, but I'm not sure. That was over an hour ago though, and the count is still increasing. @domenicr

Comment: I know the indexes are heavily fragmented. I planned on rebuilding them when the delete finished.

Comment: when we use select `count with nolock` option, it will fetch dirty reads. may be some record getting update during your select with commit.

Comment: @IndraPrakashTiwari I thought about that too, which is why I killed all of the other sessions, restarted the azure web apps and disabled all azure webjobs. So theoretically, nothing is hitting the database but my SSMS connections. Unless my original query still still rolling back as domenicr suggested.

Comment: @jrummell Any DML operation will not killed until process get rollback successfully. your kill statement will show command running successful but SQL Server does not allow this. Even if you restart the server, your database will go in recovery mode.

Comment: I restarted my workstation where I originally ran and canceled the delete script. The process is gone. After about an hour, it seems the rollback finished.

Comment: Looks like your delete was in progress. On a side note, don't try to run one large transaction (delete everything) as you may see issues if you have to rollback the transactions because of the failovers or db restarts. Split the query into multiple sub queries and delete a small range in one transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you completely ruled out anyone else modifying the table then it very well may be that the rollback is still completing. Querying the table with nolock bypasses locking so you can be reading data that is being rolled back and it may have began rolling back at the max id going backwards.  Try executing the count query without the nolock. Open a new session and do a sp_who2 and sp_lock to see if your query is being blocked.  Doing an sp_who2 will also show if there is a spid doing a rollback. Do a kill #spid with statusonly to get more info.